# Windows Desktop Gadget using jQuery to call JSON from web site

Tags: jquery, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

Before anyone says this, yes, I did read through the various examples cited here in SO but none of them did what I'm looking to do.  :)

I can get my gadget to appear in the gadget list, and I can add it to the desktop.  I'm looking to have a simple drop down list which is updated by an ajax call. The drop down list contains "To Do" categories and when a category is selected/changed, the "To Do" items will be displayed in the gadget (in the file, I wanted the results to appear in the `<div id='results'></div>` so that the drop down list is still visible in case the user needs to change To Do Categories.

I can get the drop down container to appear but when it attempts to make the ajax call, the data is not being returned.

I understand I need to put in `$.support.cors = true;` but I have no idea where that is supposed to go.  I have found tons of postings that state it needs to be added as of jQuery 1.5 but none specify WHERE it needs to go.

I took apart the StackOverflow Flaid widget and it was the most help but even in there, I cannot find any reference to the `$.support.cors = true;`

I'm so frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm) blog post cleared up the "gap" I had with CORS.  It turns out my issue wasn't with the gadget (not that I really thought it was) but more of the javascript I needed to add to my gadget.